# Is there a way to hold "STOP CASTING" for some time

Tags: google-cast

I want to make an AJAX call for analytics purpose after user clicks on STOP CASTING and before receiver application actually shutdowns. Is there any message interceptor for STOP_CASTING? Or any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot delay the stop casting behavior. There is typically a very small window where your code might have a chance to run. A more reliable way to handle analytics is to periodically post updates while the media is playing.